# Exporting an oracle table dynamically to a flat file

Tags: c++, occi

I am trying to build a C++ program using occi libraries that will take a select statement or a table name as an input and turn it into a delimited file. However, looking at the documentation, I can't find a way to export all columns of a query result into a file. Almost all examples I found were along the following lines

```
string query = "SELECT col1 FROM table1";

stmt = con->createStatement(query);
res = stmt->executeQuery();

while (res->next())
{
    outfile<<res->getInt(1)<<endl;
}
```

What i want to do is: Do a `select *` and then export the full row to the file in one go without specifying the type for each column, but I haven't been able to find something that does this.

I know that row-by-row exports are not really efficient for large sets, but I want to make this work before optimizing it.

Does anyone have any ideas around how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is no way to do this without iterating over the metadata object at least once. Since I only need to do this once per query execution I ended up writing the attribute types and column positions to a map and using that map within the result set loop to read data. Here's the code I used:

```
    res = stmt->executeQuery();
    vector<oracle::occi::MetaData> meta = res->getColumnListMetaData();
    map<int, int> mapper;

    for (int i=0; i < meta.size(); i++) {
            mapper[i] = meta[i].getInt(oracle::occi::MetaData::ATTR_DATA_TYPE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will find something like this "in the box" while using OCCI.

However using STL you can push to a stringstream the result of every iteration and when the rs->next() is NULL you can append the stringstream in the file.